# Disclosure Accessory not showing on TableViewCell xib

Tags: swift, xcode

I've added a Detail Disclosure Accessory on a TableViewCell (.xib), by setting the following on the storyboard:

[image]

However, Accessory is not showing on runtime:

[image]

Does anyone knows how to solve this issue? Anything else i should set on the Storyboard? Or is it an issue related to the usage of a .xib?

Comment: I've already checked constraints between UITableView and its superview.

Comment: Can you show us your code for `cellForRowAtIndexPath`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Joe Daniels, that cell is .xib called **SectionFooterCell**

```
class SectionFooterCell: UITableViewCell, NibLoadableView {

func setup() {
}
}
```

As this cell is used as a footer, my **cellForRowAtIndexPath** doesn't have any relation to it. But its settings are done on **viewForFooterInSection**:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let footer = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: SectionFooterCell.reuseIdentifier) as! SectionFooterCell
    footer.setup()
    return footer.contentView

}
```

---

**SOLVED**: I was returning footer.contentView, which does not include .accessoryVIew. All I had to do is to return footer itself:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let footer = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: SectionFooterCell.reuseIdentifier) as! SectionFooterCell
    footer.setup()
    return footer //ISSUE WAS HERE

}
```

Thanks @Joe Daniels for your help!

Comment: I'm returning footer.contentView, and the disclosure itself is not inside the contentView... the issue may be here

Answer (score 0):

My Understanding is that "custom" means you're going to configure the entire cell yourself. with 'custom' you're responsible for setting the entire content view of the tableViewCell. It makes sense then, that the accessory label isn't there at runtime.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions @Joe. I changed to "Basic" but it didn't work... So this was not the problem.

Comment: Actually, when changed to "Basic", I couldn't see the label either